# Close UserControl Popup with Gestures Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, user-controls

Good day, i have a Popup user control where the user interacts with gestures. What i want is that when the user taps on an image item, a method is called and the Popup closes. But the issue i am having is that, when an image item in the usercontrol is tapped, all the tap event methods in the usercontrol are triggered. I tried setting different gesturelistneners for each one but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
myPopUp = new Popup();
            myPopUp.Height = 400;
            myPopUp.Width = 400;
            //myPopUp.VerticalOffset = 100;
            myPopUp.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            myPopUp.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
            layout_menu layouts = new layout_menu();
            myPopUp.Child = layouts;
            myPopUp.IsOpen = true;

            GestureListener gesturelistener = GestureService.GetGestureListener(layouts);
            gesturelistener.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(onFirstImageTap);

            GestureListener gesturelistener2 = GestureService.GetGestureListener(layouts);
            gesturelistener2.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(onSecondImageTap);



        }

        private void onFirstImageTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            //LayoutPanel = 1;
            MessageBox.Show("First image tapped");
            myPopUp.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void onSecondImageTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Second image tapped");
            myPopUp.IsOpen = false;
        }
```

Layout_menu XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" Margin="0,0,10,0">
        <Grid x:Name="first_image_layout" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="13,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="99" Margin="18,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" Source="/Assets/Images/Navigation_Pane.png">
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="onFirstImageTap"></toolkit:GestureListener>
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="second_image_layout" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="156" Margin="13,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="99" Margin="18,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" Source="/Assets/Images/Navigation_Pane.png">
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="onSecondImageTap"></toolkit:GestureListener>
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
```

How do i close this popup when one of the image is being tapped? Solutions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is "layouts" (the child of the popup)

Comment: @ShawnKendrot yes layouts is the child of the popup and just a usercontrol which i defined in the xaml above. I will edit the question, i just noticed i did not define it correctly

Comment: @ShawnKendrot i have edited it. the Xaml above is for Layout_menu which i define as a child of the popup. Could you please take a look at it. Many Thanks

Comment: @manuelJ I don't understand why you're subscribing to the Tap event both in the code and in the XAML. The XAML should be enough

Comment: @KooKiz i did it like that before but i did not know how to close the Popup from the Layout_menu Xaml C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways to do that, but I think the best is to declare custom events in your usercontrol.

Keep the GestureListener declared in the UserControl's XAML like you did, but add two custom events in the code-behind:

```
public event EventHandler FirstImageTapped;
public event EventHandler SecondImageTapped;
```

Then, still in the UserControl, use the `onFirstImageTap` and `onSecondImageTap` methods to trigger your events:

```
private void onFirstImageTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var eventHandler = this.FirstImageTapped;

    if (eventHandler != null)
    {
        eventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

private void onSecondImageTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var eventHandler = this.SecondImageTapped;

    if (eventHandler != null)
    {
        eventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Finally, in the parent page, when creating the popup, subscribe to your custom events:

```
layout_menu layouts = new layout_menu();
layouts.FirstImageTapped += this.OnFirstImageTapped;
layouts.SecondImageTapped += this.OnSecondImageTapped;
```

And in the event handlers, close the popup:

```
private void OnFirstImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("First image tapped");
    myPopUp.IsOpen = false;
}

private void OnSecondImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Second image tapped");
    myPopUp.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: many thanks. Am still getting to grips with microsoft C# and windows phone as a whole. just wondering, if i had passed the popup as a parameter to the layouts_menu constructor and closed it from there, would that have worked?